# SQL Sum and self join?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data organised as below in table T_FORECAST

```
   Location     Sublocation     Delivery_forecast    Delivery_Date     Forecast_date
   ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1            1               100                  2020-01-01        2019-01-01
   1            2               50                   2020-01-01        2019-05-01
   1            1               90                   2020-01-01        2019-06-01
   1            2               70                   2020-01-01        2019-10-01
   . . .
```

I am trying to write a query that would output the sum of Delivery_forecast per location, Delivery_date, and Forecast_date.
in the example below, I would expect:

```
   Location     Delivery_forecast    Delivery_Date     Forecast_date
   ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1            100                  2020-01-01        2019-01-01
   1            150                  2020-01-01        2019-05-01
   1            140                  2020-01-01        2019-06-01
   1            160                  2020-01-01        2019-10-01
```

I could find the list of lines I need using the request below but I cannot find the way to get the right sum. I believe I have to do a self join

```
SELECT DISTINCT f.Location, f.Delivery_Date, f.Forecast_date
FROM T_FORECAST f
```

Comment: Can you explain the `140` and `160` values? Also, why is `2019-05-01` showing twice in the expected result?

Comment: Sorry, 2019-05-01 should appear only once, I edited to correct. 140 is the sum of 90&50, the latest forecast for location 1 as of 2019-06-01. Same logic applies for 160

Answer (score 0):

Use a cumulative sum:

```
select f.*,
       sum(delivery_forecast) over (partition by location, delivery_date order by forecast_date) as running_delivery_forecast
from T_FORECAST f;
```

Answer (score 0):

First you want an aggregation to get the sums per location and dates (`SUM(delivery_forecast)` / `GROUP BY LOCATION, DELIVERY_DATE, FORECAST_DATE`). Then you want to show a running total (`SUM OVER`). Per location, I guess. The two combined:

```
select 
  location,
  delivery_date,
  forecast_date,
  sum(delivery_forecast) as forcast_for_day,
  sum(sum(delivery_forecast)) over (partition by location
                                    order by delivery_date, forecast_date
                                   ) as forcast_cumulated
from t_forecast
group by location, delivery_date, forecast_date
order by location, delivery_date, forecast_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

They key aspect of your question is that you want to always add values from *two consecutive rows*.

To do this you can use a "window frame" according you your specific ordering. See [SQL Server - Over clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

For example:

```
select
  location,
  sum(delivery_forecast) over(
    partition by location, delivery_date 
    order by forecast_date
    rows between 1 preceding and current row -- the magic is here!
  ) as delivery_forecast,
  delivery_date, 
  forecast_date
from t_forecast
group by location, delivery_date, forecast_date
```